# How to create a new cell that repeats the same valor of rows in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

first of all, im sorry if i made some mistakes in the text, english is not my first language. My problem is the next one:

I have a cell of one column and several rows where each row have the  number of vans needed in each time zone (If A = [0,1,3,0,1,1,2,0...] it means that at 00:00 we need 0 vans, at 01:00 we need 1 van, at 02:00 we need 3 vans...etc).

The problem comes when i need to introduce the drivers needed to assume the differents vans, because each driver has, for exemple, a work shift of 3 hours, so we will have drivers when we won't need it or we will have more drivers than vans in some time zones. For exemple, using the cell A as a reference, the cell B will be: B = [0,1,3,3,2,1,2,2...] where each number is the number of drivers avialable in each time zone.

I hope that you can understand my problem and help me, i'd appreciate it.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi José - welcome - Are you looking for help to have matrix B to be created based on the values of A?

Comment: Exactly! Like I said, matrix B has to have always the same or bigger number that the matrix A